# How to justify text for a character array in java?

Tags: java, text, justify

I'm trying to return an already justified **character array** left, right and center.

Say each line has a max of 6 characters. The respective outputs in justified text would be.

```
Left:
How is
your
day

Center:
How is
 your
 day

Right:
How is
  your
   day
```

By using a for loop I add a '\n' before the line exceeds the max limit of 6 inside the array.

```
Example[3] = '\n';
```

How would I be able to return the array so that it outputs in a justified format?

I did some searching and all I was able to find was how to justify for a String.

Sorry for the horrible formatting. Not sure how to format this well.

Comment: I am not sure if its a  good idea but Did you try padding with spaces ?

Comment: Like checking the amount of spaces that are left and just add the rest with spaces? Wouldn't that get messy if I were to do centered?

Answer (score 2):

This is very basic example...

It basically pads the `String` values with spaces to provide alignment...

```
public class Align {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String values[] = new String[]{
            "How is",
            "your",
            "day"};

        int maxLength = 0;
        for (String value : values) {
            maxLength = Math.max(value.length(), maxLength);
        }

        System.out.println("Left:");
        for (String value : values) {
            System.out.println("[" + leftPad(value, maxLength) + "]");
        }
        System.out.println("\nRight:");
        for (String value : values) {
            System.out.println("[" + rightPad(value, maxLength) + "]");
        }
        System.out.println("\nCenter:");
        for (String value : values) {
            System.out.println("[" + centerPad(value, maxLength) + "]");
        }
    }

    public static String leftPad(String sValue, int iMinLength) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(iMinLength);
        sb.append(sValue);

        while (sb.length() < iMinLength) {

            sb.append(" ");

        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public static String rightPad(String sValue, int iMinLength) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(iMinLength);
        sb.append(sValue);

        while (sb.length() < iMinLength) {

            sb.insert(0, " ");

        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public static String centerPad(String sValue, int iMinLength) {

        if (sValue.length() < iMinLength) {

            int length = sValue.length();
            int left = (iMinLength - sValue.length()) / 2;
            int right = iMinLength - sValue.length() - left;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sValue);
            for (int index = 0; index < left; index++) {
                sb.insert(0, " ");
            }
            for (int index = 0; index < right; index++) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }

            sValue = sb.toString();

        }

        return sValue;

    }
}
```

Which simply outputs...

```
Left:
[How is]
[your  ]
[day   ]

Right:
[How is]
[  your]
[   day]

Center:
[How is]
[ your ]
[ day  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Commons [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) have various method to justified string in various format. like, leftpad, rightpad, centerpad